# Date is being sent as 0000-00-00 and returned as 11/30/-0001 when I use SQL update statement

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

For some reason when I edit the the date it's being sent as 0000-00-00 to the database. The wrest of the update is working as expected. I have the db rows for the dates set on type: date, default: none, and null: no.

Also tried to remove the values for the date inputs, that didn't do anything either. Please help, thank you!

```js
<?php 
include 'db.php';
$WAGE = 14;
$TAX = 0.01;
$SS = 0.062;
$MEDI = 0.0145;
$GOAL = 0.75;

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {
    // Variables
    $id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['id']);
    $begDate = htmlspecialchars($_POST['date1']);
    $endDate = htmlspecialchars($_POST['date2']);
    $hours = htmlspecialchars($_POST['hours']);
    $total = number_format($hours * $WAGE, 2, '.', '');
    $taxDeducted = number_format($total * $TAX, 2,'.', '');
    $SSDeducted = number_format($total * $SS, '2', '.', '');
    $MEDIDeducted = number_format($total * $MEDI, '2', '.', '');
    $deducted = number_format($taxDeducted + $MEDIDeducted + $SSDeducted, 2, '.', '');
    $total -= number_format($deducted, 2, '.', '');
    $save = number_format($GOAL * $total, 2, '.', '');
    $date = $_POST['date1'];
    // SQL
    $sql = "UPDATE hours SET begDate=$date, endDate=$endDate, hours=$hours, deducted=$deducted, save=$save, total=$total WHERE id=$id;";

    // EXECUTE
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
}

?>
```

```html
<?php 
include 'header.php'; 
include 'db.php';
if(isset($_GET['id'])) :
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM hours WHERE id=$id;";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $res) :
    $begDate = $res['begDate'];
    $endDate = $res['endDate'];
    $hours = $res['hours'];
    endforeach;
?>
<div class="container form bg-light p-5">
    <h1 class="text-center my-5">Add a week</h1>
    <form action="editForm.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $id; ?>" id="id">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                <input type="date" name="date1" id="date1" value="<?=$begDate;?>"  class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                <h3>TO</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 form-group">
                <input type="date" name="date2" id="date2" value="<?=$endDate;?>" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 form-group mx-auto mt-5">
                <input class="form-control" value="<?= $hours;?>" type="float" name="hours" id="hours" placeholder="Hours this period" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row text-center mt-5">
            <div class="form-group col-md-3 mx-auto">
                <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'editForm.php',
            method: 'post',
            data: $('form').serialize()
        })
        .done(function(res, status) {
            if(status == 'success') {
                window.location.href = 'index.php';
            }
        })
        .fail(function(res, status) {
            if(status == 'error') {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });
    })

</script>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Your SQL is invalid. You are missing quotes around all of your strings. So your dates look like math (subtraction)

Comment: Prepared statements should never have variables in them `UPDATE hours SET begDate=?, endDate=?, hours=?, deducted=?, save=?, total=? WHERE id=?` then bind the variables

Comment: @user3783243 binding the variables was what did it. Thank you for the help!